# Convert Rotation matrix to Euler angles $~zyz~ (y$ convention$)$ analytically.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

The rotation matrix of Euler angle $ZYZ$ is:
$$
R_{z1}=\left[\cos(\psi),\sin(\psi),0;-\sin(\psi),\cos(\psi),0;0,0,1 \right];
$$
$$
R_y=[\cos(\theta),0,-\sin(\theta);0,1,0;\sin(\theta),0,\cos(\theta)];
$$
$$
R_{z2}=[\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi),0;-\sin(\phi),\cos(\phi),0;0,0,1];
$$
$R=Rz1*Ry*Rz2~$;
$$
R=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\phi}\cos{\theta}\cos{\psi}-\sin{\phi}\sin{\psi} &\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}\cos{\psi}+\cos{\phi}\sin{\psi}& -\sin{\theta} \cos{\psi}\\-\cos{\phi}\cos{\theta}\sin{\psi}-\sin{\phi}\cos{\psi}&-\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}\sin{\psi}+\cos{\phi}\cos{\psi}& \sin{\theta}\sin{\psi}\\\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}&\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}&\cos{\theta}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
But if I have a rotation matrix R2 and I want to get Euler angle in $ZYZ~
(Y$ convention$)$ I can't find how to do it exactly.

for other Euler angles there is a solution, for example, see:

http://www.gregslabaugh.net/publications/euler.pdf

Why the following give me wrong answer when calculated in matlab:

$$ϕ=\text{atan}\left(\frac{R(3,2)}{R(3,1)}\right); ~~θ=\text{acos}(R(3,3)); ~~Ψ=\text{atan}\left(-\frac{R(2,3)}{R(1,3)}\right)$$

Comment: I started out on the MathJax equations, please correct them so that they are pretty and understandable. After that, we can discuss finding the solution.

Comment: The paper you cited uses the method of dividing certain terms of the matrix, in order to cancel out terms and get convenient expressions for the angles. Can you find such divisions to solve for the angles in this case?

Comment: yes, I wrote it now, but if you test it on matlab it won't work, I can't understand why

Comment: Okay good, you found the formulas! Remember that the inverse trigonometric function are multi-valued functions and therefore a program might have difficulty deciding which solution you want. A good approch is to limit each angle to $-180^{\circ} \ldots + 180^{\circ}$. What were the initial angles that you used, and what were the angles that you obtained?

Comment: I took the extracted euler angles and use them again to create the rotation matrix, but now this new rotation matrix rotate a vector v differently then the original rotation matrix, how its possible?

Comment: Without actually seeing your code, it's impossible to say. I think the math works. That is, the extraction equations that you wrote do look correct. If I were you, I would test out **only the math part** without any visualisations. Try to set some values to the angles, then calculate the matrix and then try to extract the angles. Do you get the same angles that you started with? If not, then research where the error can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach to extract correctly Euler angles from a rotation matrix for any sequence of angles is using the [$\mathrm{atan2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function. In the end, it is done in the same way (and maybe also explained why) in the text you linked. Note that compared to other inverse trigonometric functions, $\mathrm{atan2}$ has the range $(-\pi,\pi]$ (the full circle).

In your case of the $z$-$y$-$z$ rotation, if $\sin\theta\neq 0$, then
$$
\phi=\mathrm{atan2}(R_{32},R_{31}), \quad \psi=\mathrm{atan2}(R_{23},-R_{13}).
$$
We can obtain the $\theta$ angle from the last row or the last column of $R$. For example, considering the last row of $R$, we have
$$
R_{31}\cos\phi+R_{32}\sin\phi=\sin\theta(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)=\sin\theta
$$
so
$$
\theta=\mathrm{atan2}(R_{31}\cos\phi+R_{32}\sin\phi,R_{33}).
$$

For these Euler angles to be well-defined, the condition $\sin\theta\neq 0$ is required (that is, $\theta\neq k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$). Otherwise, e.g., if $\theta=0$, the two $z$-angles are not uniquely defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you know the tangent of an angle, there is an indeterminacy of a half-turn on the angle.

I recommend to avoid the use of the arc cosine, and prefer the arc tangent, with

$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt{(\cos\phi\sin\theta)^2+{(\sin\phi\sin\theta)^2}}}{\cos\theta}.$$ Beware that this drops the sign of $\sin\theta$.

After obtaining the angles, plug them back to compare to the original  matrix and adjust for the quadrants. (Sorry, I don't have time to deal with the complete discussion.)