# Rotation matrix decomposition into mixed local/global Euler angles

Tags: 3d, matrix-decomposition, eulers-method

I am trying to decompose a rotation matrix into Euler angles.
The standard ways appear to work fine to find the rotations around the moving/local axes (example 1) OR to find the rotations around the global or fixed axes (example 2).
I struggle with mixing local and global axes, as it is required for my application:
**My first rotation has to be around global Y, second around local X, third around local Y.**

I attempted an [illustration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96U54.png), and set a [jupyter notebook here](https://nbviewer.org/urls/plik.root.gg/file/PmMah6RnlmsfKNTc/2hexHmDlXKcmfo8k/20220712.ipynb)

There are a few relevant discussions but I still can’t seem to find my away around!

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/337882/mixing-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-3d-rotations
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128589/decomposing-rotation-matrix-x-y-z-cartesian-angles
- [Convert Rotation matrix to Euler angles $~zyz~ (y$ convention$)$ analytically.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328656/convert-rotation-matrix-to-euler-angles-zyz-y-convention-analytically)

Based on the following rotation matrix as an example:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{R} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.83101165 & 0.17101007 & -0.52931577\\
0.12940952 & 0.8660254 & 0.48296291 \\
0.54099243 & -0.46984631 & 0.69754687
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

#### **1) Example 1 of xyz rotation with local axes**

Rz @ Ry @ Rx, with:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l l}
\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{lG},\,xyz} & = \mathbf{R_{z}} \mathbf{R_{y}} \mathbf{R_{x}} \\
\\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\gamma & \sin\gamma & 0\\
-\sin\gamma & \cos\gamma & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\beta & 0 & -\sin\beta \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin\beta & 0 & \cos\beta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos\alpha & \sin\alpha \\
0 & -\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\beta\:\cos\gamma \;&\;
\sin\alpha\:\sin\beta\:\cos\gamma+\cos\alpha\:\sin\gamma \;&\;
\cos\alpha\:\sin\beta\:\cos\gamma-\sin\alpha\:\sin\gamma \;\;\; \\
-\cos\beta\:\sin\gamma \;&\;
-\sin\alpha\:\sin\beta\:\sin\gamma+\cos\alpha\:\cos\gamma \;&\;
\cos\alpha\:\sin\beta\:\sin\gamma+\sin\alpha\:\cos\gamma \;\;\;  \\
\sin\beta \;&\; -\sin\alpha\:\cos\beta \;&\; \cos\alpha\:\cos\beta \;\;\;
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}
$$

Solving for this:

$$
\alpha=\mathrm{arctan2}(-R_{21},R_{22}) = 0.59276  (rad) = 33.96 (deg)\\
\beta=\mathrm{arctan2}(R_{20},{\sqrt{\mathbf{R}_{00}^2+\mathbf{R}_{10}^2}}) = 0.57161668  (rad) = 32.75122352 (deg)\\
\gamma=\mathrm{arctan2}(-R_{10},R_{00}) = -0.15448448 (rad) = -8.85130893 (deg)\\
$$

#### **2) Example 2 of xyz rotation with global axes**

Rz @ Ry @ Rx, with:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l l}
\mathbf{R_{Gl,\;XYZ}} & = \mathbf{R_{Z}} \mathbf{R_{Y}} \mathbf{R_{X}} \\
\\ 
& = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\gamma & -\sin\gamma & 0\\
\sin\gamma & \cos\gamma & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\beta & 0 & \sin\beta \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin\beta & 0 & \cos\beta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \\
0 & \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\ 
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\beta\:\cos\gamma \;&\;
\sin\alpha\:\sin\beta\:\cos\gamma-\cos\alpha\:\sin\gamma \;&\;
\cos\alpha\:\sin\beta\:cos\gamma+\sin\alpha\:\sin\gamma \;\;\; \\
\cos\beta\:\sin\gamma \;&\;
\sin\alpha\:\sin\beta\:\sin\gamma+\cos\alpha\:\cos\gamma \;&\;
\cos\alpha\:\sin\beta\:\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha\:\cos\gamma \;\;\;  \\
-\sin\beta \;&\; \sin\alpha\:\cos\beta \;&\; \cos\alpha\:\cos\beta \;\;\;
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Solving for this:

$$
\alpha=\mathrm{arctan2}(R_{21},R_{22}) = = -0.5927662886828803 (rad) = -33.96300657916242 (deg)\\
\beta=\mathrm{arctan2}(-R_{20},{\sqrt{\mathbf{R}_{00}^2+\mathbf{R}_{10}^2}}) = -0.5716166844955842 (rad) = -32.75122352085813 (deg)\\
\gamma=\mathrm{arctan2}(-R_{10},R_{00}) = 0.15448448400601972 (rad) = 8.851308933801198 (deg)\\
$$

### My problem is when I am trying to mix the global and local axes

α is the first rotation around the Global Y axis,
β is the second rotation around the Local y axis,
γ is the third rotation around the Local y axis

The order or rotation is right to left, so $R_{M}$ = $R_{M,y}$ @ $R_{M,x}$ @ $R_{M,Y}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l l}
\displaystyle R_{M,Yxy} = \left[\begin{matrix}\cos{\left(\gamma \right)} & 0 & - \sin{\left(\gamma \right)}\\0 & 1 & 0\\\sin{\left(\gamma \right)} & 0 & \cos{\left(\gamma \right)}\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & \cos{\left(\beta \right)} & \sin{\left(\beta \right)}\\0 & - \sin{\left(\beta \right)} & \cos{\left(\beta \right)}\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}\cos{\left(\alpha \right)} & 0 & \sin{\left(\alpha \right)}\\0 & 1 & 0\\- \sin{\left(\alpha \right)} & 0 & \cos{\left(\alpha \right)}\end{matrix}\right]
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l l}
\displaystyle R_{M,Yxy} = \left[\begin{matrix}\sin{\left(\alpha \right)} \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} \cos{\left(\beta \right)} + \cos{\left(\alpha \right)} \cos{\left(\gamma \right)} & \sin{\left(\beta \right)} \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} & \sin{\left(\alpha \right)} \cos{\left(\gamma \right)} - \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} \cos{\left(\alpha \right)} \cos{\left(\beta \right)}\\- \sin{\left(\alpha \right)} \sin{\left(\beta \right)} & \cos{\left(\beta \right)} & \sin{\left(\beta \right)} \cos{\left(\alpha \right)}\\- \sin{\left(\alpha \right)} \cos{\left(\beta \right)} \cos{\left(\gamma \right)} + \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} \cos{\left(\alpha \right)} & - \sin{\left(\beta \right)} \cos{\left(\gamma \right)} & \sin{\left(\alpha \right)} \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} + \cos{\left(\alpha \right)} \cos{\left(\beta \right)} \cos{\left(\gamma \right)}\end{matrix}\right]\end{array}
\end{equation}

## Does this approach make sense? If yes, how would you go solving for

this?

Solving for this, with:
$\alpha$ = ???
$\beta$ = ???
$\gamma$ = ???

Edit: it is a standard Local rotation as initially the two Y axes are similar... so example 1 is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any 3 angle rotation scheme, there are actually four reference frames at play. Lets define:

| Frame | Description |
| --- | --- |
| $G$ | Global frame before rotations |
| $L_1$ | Local frame after 1st rotation |
| $L_2$ | Local frame after 2nd rotation |
| $L_3$ | Local frame after all 3 rotations |

Since the before the first rotation we are always in the global frame, your worry about mixing global and local frames is unfounded. The rotation sequence you appear to be describing is actually just the common 2-1-2 or Y-X-Y rotation sequence. See Appendix C in *Analytical Mechanics of Space Systems* by Schaub and Junkins for example (google for pdf). I would highly recommend working through the first few sections of the attitude kinematics chapter in this book as well to improve your facility with composite rotations.

Finally, check
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix

for the inverse transformation you appear to be seeking. Specifically, see the $Y_1 X_2 Y_3$ column of the second table in the Rotation Matrix section.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks So Much for taking a look!
You are right, my Yxy matrix was not right...
I edited my post and it looks "ok" to me now, but I'm not sure where to start to solve it...?
I have also edited the beginning of the post to add a picture describing the application, and a jupyter notebook with 3D graphs just in case it is easier to follow

Comment: You appear to now be erroneously using beta as a name for both the first and third rotation, these angles should almost definitely be represented by two different variables. I think I see what you're trying to do now, though, so I'll edit my ansewer and do my best to point you in the right direction based on that. Please correct the question for future viewers though.

Comment: I've edited the final matrices with three distinct angles (alpha, beta, gamma) thank you for pointing that out! I'll get the book you mentioned and work through the appendix, and update the answer on this thread :)

Comment: Great, don’t forget to accept the answer once satisfied you’re headed in the right direction:-)

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed the standard rotation as the Y axes are initially the same!!!